# eledmac and two column footnotes

Tags: horizontal-alignment, footnotes, two-column, eledmac

I like `dblfnote` and have been working with it for a good while. Now my footnotes are just getting too long and the typesetting results accordingly undesirable, they would be way better if footnotes could be split across pages.

`eledmac` shows this desired behaviour. The following command almost gets it right:

```
\usepackage{eledmac}
\foottwocolX{A}
\let\footnote\footnoteA
```

But I didn't manage to have the colums typeset justified. For some reason my

```
\renewcommand*{\twocolfootfmt}[3]{...\justified...}
```

isn't recognized. Does anyone know how this works?

Comment: could you open a ticket on the github ? I think this could be an option on eledmac.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It works if you remove `\raggedright` from the definition of `\twocolfootfmtX`. In my example I use the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to do so.

[Note: For justified two-column typesetting, loading the [`microtype`](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) package is strongly recommended.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eledmac}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\twocolfootfmtX}{\raggedright}{}{}{}

\foottwocolX{A}
\let\footnote\footnoteA

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]\footnote{\lipsum*[2-8]}

\end{document}
```

[image]