# two columns of footnotes in beamer?

Tags: beamer, footnotes, columns

I have a beamer frame with six fairly short footnotes on it.  This takes up a fair bit of vertical space and not much horizontal space, so I'd like to put the footnotes into a two-column layout (even though the frame content itself is one column).

I tried `dblfnote` package (had no discernible effect) and the `eledmac` advice seen in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/93763/19160), but I couldn't even get the document to compile with `eledmac` package included (something about `\lemma` being already defined).

How can I get Beamer to use a two-column environment for footnotes?  Ideally I would like to be able to switch this on or off for different frames, but I'd settle for a document-wide solution.

PS: I know footnotes are discouraged in Beamer, but I'm not asking for presentation design advice here.