# How can I set short footnotes next to each other (two-column style)?

Tags: footnotes, two-column, footmisc, bigfoot

When having a comparatively large number of footnotes that are each very short (URLs say), it sometimes looks weird to have them stack up to a high footnote tower, especially in a `minipage` or some similarly confined space.

[image: four URLs one under the other]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks=true]{hyperref}
\newcommand{\footurl}[1]{\footnote{\url{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
As Linux Jabber clients there are for example Pidgin\footurl{http://www.pidgin.im/}, Kopete\footurl{http://kopete.kde.org/}, Gajim\footurl{http://gajim.org/} and Psi\footurl{http://psi-im.org/}.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Intuitively, I'd like to see these footnotes next to each other, like so:

[image: 2x2 footnotes]

Is there any package that does this for me? Or any other way?

If at all possible I'd like not to go all [two-columned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/93763/13450) with all my footnotes.

---

**Edit**

Just for reference, I'll show the two closest solutions so far. The first is the `eledmac` solution I [linked to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/93763/13450) myself which can be used locally when not changing the `\footnote` command. <strike>It's not compatible with `fnpct` however.</strike> It can be made to work with `fnpct` with the excellent extension capabilities of this package, so the following image uses `\AdaptNoteNoMult{\footnoteA}`.

[image: 3+1 footnotes]

The second is the solution suggested by jon which uses `bigfoot` and the `para` option. It is compatible with `fnpct` which I used in the following example but it inherits `manyfoot`'s "feature" of escaping minipages so the length of the following example is still a huge understatement. It's also not properly aligned so it doesn't look satisfactory on its own.

[image: 2x2 but not aligned]

Comment: And sorry for the footnotes and the punctuation. Yes, I do use [fnpct](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56094/13450) in my actual document.

Comment: Have you considered using the `footmisc` package with the `para` option?

Comment: It seems that no footnote package can do what you are looking for out of the box. The closest is perhaps `\usepackage[para]{bigfoot}\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default}`, which will use paragraphed notes except when `bigfoot`'s underlying 'badness' algorithm decides that it would look to worse if the footnote in question is started on a new line. It is very impressive, but unfortunately it can't match manually placed mixed short and long footnotes you'll see in some academic publications. If only it could be extended to do (only) 1, 2, or 3 short notes per line. Way above my pay grade, though!

Comment: @Mico Maybe I'm doing something wrong here but I had indeed tried `\usepackage[para]{footmisc}` but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: @jon I see ... it goes in the right direction indeed but looks quite ugly :/

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, I don't find the setting very useful, though it seems a neat trick that could be improved on (just not by me).

Comment: @jon Yeah, if the paragraph could somehow be made two-columned locally, that would be the desired output I guess.

Comment: have you considered the [`eledmac`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/eledmac/eledmac.pdf) package? (see section 24.2)

Comment: @dcmst I just added an image showing the closest solutions, `eledmac` and `bigfoot`. I used the code I linked to for my `eledmac` "solution". If there is any way it can be modified to achieve the desired output, please let me know.

Comment: And just as a side-note, in my actual document `eledmac` does some weird sh...enanigans. It actually doubles every footnote but not even in an aabbcc fashion but abcabc. Crazy :)

Comment: i expect i could make a 2col option for footmisc, but it would never be ready to solve today's problem.  if anyone else can do it "quickly" i'll happily merge the changes with the current release

Comment: Then, if you had to suggest a single package able to create all kind of footnotes easily, which one would you pick, footmisc, yafoot, bigfoot...?

Answer (score 3):

There is a package [`dblfnote`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dblfnote) which can do it for you.  Because it is a little bit old there can be other problems occur (for your MWE there will come up an warning with option `hidelinks` of package `hyperref`.  I commented the minipage in your MWE to get the wanted result.

New MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{dblfnote}  % Two footnotes in one line      % <========== new
\DFNalwaysdouble       % sets footnote always double    % <========== new

\usepackage[hidelinks=true]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\footurl}[1]{\footnote{\url{#1}}}
\begin{document}
%\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}                            % <========== 
As Linux Jabber clients there are for example 
Pidgin\footurl{http://www.pidgin.im/}, 
Kopete\footurl{http://kopete.kde.org/}, Gajim\footurl{http://gajim.org/} 
and Psi\footurl{http://psi-im.org/}. 
%\end{minipage}                                          % <========== 
\end{document}
```

and the result is:

[image]

Comment: That's pretty cool but there are two bummers: that it doesn't work in minipages and that you can't switch it on and off. While "try single column" is the default, you still get footnotes that only use half the space available to them. I consider this double footnote thing a special case and it would be great if there was a package that doesn't touch footnotes at all *unless* a special command is used. It would even be understandable and okay if this package terribly crashed and burned and sold your grandmother when you mix normal and double footnotes on the same (mini)page.