# Double spacing in body but not two-column footnotes with eledmac package

Tags: footnotes, two-column, line-spacing, setspace, eledmac

With two-column footnotes using `eledmac` (based on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93763/eledmac-and-two-column-footnotes)), line spacing via `setspace` is applied to footnotes as well. How can I preserve single spacing in these two-column footnotes?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{eledmac}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\twocolfootfmtX}{\raggedright}{}{}{}
\foottwocolX{A}
\let\footnote\footnoteA
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1]\footnote{\lipsum*[3-4]}\lipsum*[6-7] % text AND footnote are double-spaced!
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must migrate to reledmac and use the `\bhooknoteX` and `\bhookgroupX` commands.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\arrangementX[A]{twocol}
\colalignX{\justifying}
\makeatletter
 \bhooknoteX[A]{\setstretch {\setspace@singlespace}}
 \bhookgroupX[A]{\setstretch {\setspace@singlespace}}
\makeatother
\let\footnote\footnoteA
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1]\footnote{\lipsum*[3-4]}\lipsum*[6-7] % text AND footnote are double-spaced!
\end{document}
```

In this MWE, I have also change the way you modify notes alignement, using the `\colalignX` command.

Comment: How would I do the same for paragraph-arranged notes? If I set `A` to `paragraph` I get an `unidentified control sequence` error at `\makeatother`.

Comment: sorry? I don't understand your question.

Comment: Apologies. Example: How can I make a B series of notes also single-spaced but with `\arrangementX[B]{paragraph}`? Simply adding this line then below it copying the lines from your example between `\makeatletter` and `let\footnote\footnoteA` (inclusive) and changing them to refer to `B` creates an error.

Comment: Please provides your MWE. It will be clearer.

Comment: Apologies again: because I've begun using critical rather than familiar footnotes, I had to make a new MWE, so I posted a new question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279347/reledmac-single-spaced-two-col-and-paragraph-footnotes-in-a-double-spaced-docum.