# reledmac: single-spaced two-col and paragraph footnotes in a double-spaced document

Tags: spacing, footnotes, reledmac

Building on [a similar question I asked, and its answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279040/double-spacing-in-body-but-not-two-column-footnotes-with-eledmac-package): Given that in `reledmac` a series (`B` below) of two-column critical footnotes can be made single-spaced in a double-spaced document according to the method below, how can a series (`A` below) of paragraph footnotes also be made single-spaced? Using the same method for `A` (which works for `B`) returns an error.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[series={A,B},noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}

\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
%\makeatletter    % make A single-spaced: doesn't work
% \Xbhooknote[A]{\setstretch {\setspace@singlespace}}
% \Xbhookgroup[A]{\setstretch {\setspace@singlespace}}
%\makeatother    % "unidentified control sequence" error here, if lines are uncommented
%\let\footnote\footnoteA

\Xarrangement[B]{twocol}
\Xcolalign{\justifying}
\makeatletter  % make B single-spaced (no errors)
 \Xbhooknote[B]{\setstretch {\setspace@singlespace}}
 \Xbhookgroup[B]{\setstretch {\setspace@singlespace}}
\makeatother
\let\footnote\footnoteB

\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\lipsum*[1]\edtext{Lipsum}{
    \Afootnote{\lipsum*[3]}  % paragraph footnote: needs to be single-spaced
    \Bfootnote{\lipsum*[4]}}  % two-col footnote: is single-spaced
\lipsum*[6-7]
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For some technical reasons, the setting of Xbhookgroup on paragraphed notes is executing immediatly when calling `\Xbhookgroup`. You have loaded `setspace` after imakeidx, so `\setspace@singlespace` is not yet know when `\Xbhookgroup` is called. Just call `setspace` after you reledmac setting. It is also need to prevent false line.
2. the doublespacing option of `setspace`is problematic, as it make difficult the calculation of some internal parameters of reledmac for paragraphed notes. Use `\AtBeginDocument{\doublespacing}` instead (that just tell to LaTeX to execute `\doublespacing` on `\begin{document}`, so after the internal calculation of reledmac.

As you applies the sames hook to multiple series, you can ignore the optional argument.

So the final MWE is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}




\usepackage[]{setspace}
\AtBeginDocument{\doublespacing}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[series={A,B},noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
\Xarrangement[B]{twocol}
\Xcolalign{\justifying}
\makeatletter 
 \Xbhooknote{\setstretch {\setspace@singlespace}}
 \Xbhookgroup{\setstretch {\setspace@singlespace}}
\makeatother   

\begin{document}

\beginnumbering
\pstart
\lipsum*[1]\edtext{Lipsum}{
    \Afootnote{\lipsum*[3]}  % paragraph footnote: needs to be single-spaced
    \Bfootnote{\lipsum*[4]}}  % two-col footnote: is single-spaced
\lipsum*[6-7]
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ps : if my answer is ok, I will add it in the examples folder.

Comment: Thanks, and please do. By the way, my model for this layout is the Delphin Classics series of Latin texts ([example](https://archive.org/stream/delphinclassics177valp#page/402/mode/2up)).

Comment: Done on https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/commit/2d6659d51812a72eda77e9a7f6fbc6ecbe88f785