# reledmac: in double-spaced document, single-spaced two-col footnotes not aligned

Tags: vertical-alignment, footnotes, line-spacing, reledmac

In a double-spaced document with two-column single-spaced footnotes in the reledmac environment (using [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279347/reledmac-single-spaced-two-col-and-paragraph-footnotes-in-a-double-spaced-docum)), the lines across the footnote columns don't line up vertically. This issue disappears if either double-spacing or the `\Xbhooknote` option is removed, but I'd like to keep both while preserving footnote alignment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[]{setspace}
\AtBeginDocument{\doublespacing}
\Xarrangement[A]{twocol}
\Xcolalign{\justifying}
\makeatletter
    \Xbhooknote{\setstretch {\setspace@singlespace}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \beginnumbering
        \pstart
            Ecce \edtext{ipse lorus:}{\Afootnote{i.e. Lorem ipsum.}} \lipsum*[1] \edtext{Haec hactenus.}{\Afootnote{\lipsum*[2]}}
        \pend
    \endnumbering
\end{document}
```

[image: reledmac single-spaced two-col alignment]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Quick answer:

- Download the version, 2.7.1, just send on CTAN or on https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/archive/mac2.7.1-par2.6.2.zip
- Use the `\Xbhookgroup` hook to change also change the line spacing

See this MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[]{setspace}
\AtBeginDocument{\doublespacing}
\Xarrangement[A]{twocol}
\Xcolalign{\justifying}
\makeatletter
    \Xbhooknote{\setstretch {\setspace@singlespace}}
    \Xbhookgroup{\setstretch {\setspace@singlespace}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \beginnumbering
        \pstart
            Ecce \edtext{ipse lorus:}{\Afootnote{i.e. Lorem ipsum.}} \lipsum*[1] \edtext{Haec hactenus.}{\Afootnote{\lipsum*[2]}}
        \pend
    \endnumbering
\end{document}
```

### Comment

The main problem is that, when splitting in two column the contents of notes, reledmac add vertical space (`\splittopskip`). This vertical space is calculated on the based of the `\baselineskip` when outputting the notes, which is not affected by `Xbhooknote` hook, which concerns only the way footnote are stored in a temporary box. So we also need to set it when outputing the footnotes group, and we use `\Xbhookgroup`.
But it was buged for twocol and threecol footnotes arrangement. It should be solved in 2.7.1