# How to avoid a line spacing issue using the reledmac package's footnotes with line spacing commands from memoir or setspace?

Tags: footnotes, memoir, line-spacing, reledmac, setspace

I have an issue in which using reledmac together with either memoir's line spacing commands (e.g. `\DoubleSpacing`) or setspace's `\setstretch` command does not produce the desired result.

Specifically, I want to adjust the line spacing of the main text without affecting the line spacing of footnotes. Normally, the above mentioned commands function in this way. However, reledmac introduces its own footnotes of type `\footnoteX` (familiar footnotes) and `\Xfootnote` (critical footnotes), and these reledmac footnotes are affected by the line spacing commands.

See this minimal working example in which I use three types of footnotes: the standard `\footnote` (which functions as expected) and then reledmac's `\footnoteA` and `\Afootnote` (which do not function as expected):

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\DoubleSpacing

\usepackage{reledmac}

\begin{document}

\beginnumbering
\pstart

    Some text. Some text. \edtext{Some text}{\Afootnote{Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text.}}. Some text. Some text.\footnote{Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.} Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text.\footnoteA{Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text.}

\pend
\endnumbering
    
\end{document}
```

This is what the footnotes look like:

[image]

How can I avoid this issue? I tried in vain to figure out how to customize line spacing in the reledmac footnotes using the reledmac documentation. Thanks in advance for any help.

---

**Edit**: In my actual project, the familiar footnote set `\footnoteA` should be in two columns. The solution should not prevent the two columns from being aligned with each other.

Comment: Following your edit, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is apparently necessary to switch back to single spacing before a familiar or critical footnote is set. So, with the `memoir` class and its commands for spacing:

**Edit** for addressing the additional problem raised in the comment, `\bhookgroupX{\SingleSpacing*}` is also needed when notes are set in more than one column (see [reledmac: in double-spaced document, single-spaced two-col footnotes not aligned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281620))

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\DoubleSpacing

\usepackage{reledmac}

\Xbeforeinserting{\SingleSpacing*}
\beforeinsertingX{\SingleSpacing*}
\bhookgroupX{\SingleSpacing*}

\arrangementX{twocol} %for demonstrating it with two columns

\begin{document}

\beginnumbering
\pstart

Some text. Some text. \edtext{Some text}{\Afootnote{Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text.}}. Some text. Some text.\footnote{Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.} Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text.\footnoteA{Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text.}

\pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks like it is on the right track. I noticed a problem that was not captured by my MWE. In my actual project I need the familiar footnote set `\footnoteA` to be in two columns. Using `\beforeinsertingX{\SingleSpacing*}` changes spacing to single space. However, it affects the alignment of the two columns such that the second column does not start flush with the first column, but about a half line lower. Any ideas about what causes this and how to fix it?

Comment: Yes, now with the `\bhookgroupX{\SingleSpacing*}` line added it works with two-column footnotes. Thank you very much.