# How to Adjust the Gap Between 2-Columned Footnotes Using Eledmac

Tags: footnotes, double-sided, eledmac

Some time ago, a question was posed as to how to split two-columned footnotes across pages, suggesting use of the package *eledmac*:

[eledmac and two column footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93763/eledmac-and-two-column-footnotes)

User lockstep posted the following (simple and efficient) answer:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eledmac}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\twocolfootfmtX}{\raggedright}{}{}{}

\foottwocolX{A}
\let\footnote\footnoteA

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1]\footnote{\lipsum*[2-8]}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following output (partly shown here, but spans two pages in its entirety):

[image]

QUESTION: Can the prior code be simply modified in order to adjust (in this case, lessen) the width between the two columns; and secondly, is it possible to indent the the footnote?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of `eledmac` two-column "familiar" footnotes is set by the `\hsizetwocolX` option, where `X` is the note series (A in your example) and the argument in `{}` sets the width for the column (`.45\hsize` is the standard setting apparently). So for reducing the space between columns I'd start to increase the width,  e.g. with `\hsizetwocolX[A]{.46\hsize}` and keep increasing towards `0.5\hsize` until it looks acceptable. See chapter 5.4.7 "Options for footnotes in columns" in the eledmac documentation (p. 31 in my copy).

`\parindentX[A]` will enable indentation (ch. 5.4.5 "Styles of note content" in the documentation).

Please note that `eledmac` has been superseded by `reledmac`.

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer. I am able to successfully adjust the width between the two columns now; however, when I use \parindentX[A] --- I get the error message, ``undefined control sequence' . I have inserted it after \begin{document}. Is there something I may be missing? Thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error when I use `\parindentX[A]` in your MWE. It works either before or after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Thank you. The problem must be on my end.

Comment: In complement to henryflower answer : event if the settings can be made both in preamble and after \begin{document}, I recommand, as for all general settings, to make them in the preamble.